# Corda - Purpose of NULL_PARTY

Tags: corda

What is the purpose of `NullKeys.NULL_PARTY`?

For example, when should I use

```
party: AbstractParty = NullKeys.NULL_PATRY
```

Rather than

```
party: AbstractParty? = null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
party: AbstractParty? = null
```

The above defines a nullable variable i.e. party will either be an `AbstractParty` or it will be `null`

```
party: AbstractParty = NullKeys.NULL_PARTY
```

The above on the other hand, will never result in party being `null`, but rather you'll end up with an `AnonymousParty` with a `null` public key.

`NULL_PARTY` could come in useful during unit testing, particularly when testing for equality, but it's not advised to use it for production code.

Answer (score -1):

`!= NULL_PARTY` works just as well as `!= null` and removes the nuisance of not-null assertion/safety operators when you can be sure the value will not be used, e.g. an `owner` for a state that has not been purchased by one.

See also sample uses in [Corda's repo](https://github.com/corda/corda/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=NULL_PARTY&type=).