# Corda - Can we use NULL_PARTY in production code (again)?

Tags: corda

In relation to a previous question I asked [Corda - Purpose of NULL_PARTY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54450888/corda-purpose-of-null-party) Cais pointed out that `NULL_PARTY` probably shouldn't be used in production code, but having spoken with a few more developers at R3, I want to introduce a use-case where this might be useful.

I have a particular use case where a party might be a signing party on the Corda network,  or a non-signing party not on the Corda network, but the other participants still need to be aware that this party is "off-chain".

With that in mind, I've implemented an off-chain party:

```
import net.corda.core.crypto.NullKeys.NULL_PARTY
import net.corda.core.identity.AbstractParty
import net.corda.core.utilities.OpaqueBytes

class OffChainParty(val reference: String) : AbstractParty(party.owningKey) {

    companion object {
        private val party = NULL_PARTY
    }

    override fun nameOrNull() = party.nameOrNull()

    override fun ref(bytes: OpaqueBytes) = party.ref(bytes)
}
```

States that potentially require off-chain participation would be implemented like this:

```
data class ObligationState(
    val obligor: AbstractParty,
    val obligee: AbstractParty,
    val insurer: AbstractParty
) : ContractState {
    val participants: List<AbstractParty> 
        get() = listOf(obligor, obligee, insurer).filter { it !is OffChainParty }
}
```

We could then include signing participants like so:

```
val state = ObligationState(alice, bob, charlie) // assume they're all known parties.
```

And we could include non-signing participants like so:

```
val state = ObligationState(alice, bob, OffChainParty("acme technology"))
```

**Q & A**

Q: Why don't you just use `AbstractParty?` and make it `null`?

A: Because the other participants can't determine who `null` is, but they can determine who "acme technology" is, without requiring them to sign.

Q: Why don't you just use a `String` reference, instead of circumventing `AbstractParty`?

A: because sometimes we want the party to sign, so they have to be a *real* `Party`, and other times, we just want to know who they are, regardless of whether they're "on-chain" or not.

Any thoughts on this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very nice idea, you would essentially embed the OffChainParty into the state (and therefore onto the ledger) whilst not making them a required member of the network the node is attached to.

The only thing I would say is, do you need NULL_PARTY at all, and you will have to be careful to ensure you always filter your participants.

There is some interesting work coming up about introducing `Destination` to Corda, which could be something like `NetworkDestination` or `OffNetworkDestination` so keep an eye on the open source repo.

Comment: I guess the use of `NULL_PARTY` in this instance is just helpful in implementing `AbstractParty` in a way that encapsulates an existing implementation, rather than using a custom implementation which would do exactly the same thing.